# LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL is not working with root

Tags: cocoa

LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL is not returning all applications when I run the xcode with debug executable as root.If run with admin it is returning all installed apps.

Why is this strange behaviour any ideas.

Regards,
Akbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user on a Mac OS X system has their own Launch Services database cache file. The exact set of currently "installed" (or known) applications for one user may not necessarily match the set of known apps for another user, including the root user. You will likely need to wrap your LS commands like in the following code:

```
int err = 0;
uid_t uid = getuid();
uid_t euid = geteuid();

if (uid != euid) {
    err = seteuid(uid);
    if (err != 0) {
        NSLog(@"seteuid(uid) returned %d", err);
    }
}

// do your LS commands, etc.

// then restore root privs:
err = seteuid(euid);
if (err != 0) {
    NSLog(@"seteuid(euid) returned %d", err);
}
```

(Note that I am assuming here that you are not logged in the GUI as the root user, in which case the above method isn't going to work since both the uid and the euid would be the same).

Comment: Thanks for your response,

I have tried writing LSCopyFromURLsForURL after setting seteuid,it didn't work. Though I have not logged in the GUI as root user since my application is a launch deamon,  the uid and euid are
"0", even tried setting the seteuid to a random number(without
validating uid != euid), which succeeds but still not getting the list of all apps.


What might be the problem.